# CakePHP- Tree Behavior custom ordering

Tags: cakephp, tree, behavior

I have a Post model which has Tree Behavior.
In the view for each post there is a order text input field.
After submiting this fields I get id => order value.
So now I have to moveUp or moveDown each post depending on its order value to reorder the tree.

Example (the titles are examples just to follow the sorting order):

Before:

```
Post1 - order:20
_Post1.2 - order:20
_Post1.1 - order:10
__Post1.1.1 - order:10
__Post1.1.3 - order:30
__Post1.1.2 - order:20
_Post1.3 - order:30
Post2 - order:10
```

After:

```
Post2 - order:10
Post1 - order:20
_Post1.1 - order:10
__Post1.1.1 - order:10
__Post1.1.2 - order:20
__Post1.1.3 - order:30
_Post1.2 - order:20
_Post1.3 - order:30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reorder` function. Check here - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1355/reorder

Comment: `reorder` is based on a field in the database. I need reorder based on other user defined values.

Comment: hmm, got you. sounds complicated. If any idea comes in my mind then I'll try to share :)

Comment: To be able to use reorder I added a new `sort` column in the database which to store the order. So now I have the function

Comment: funny! I thought you wanted to sort differently for each user. BTW, I faced the same problem and had to re-wrote the reorder function myself. They normally run a separate query for each item. You can do the whole thing with a single nested query, which will be way faster than theirs.

Comment: can you show some example or peace of code to do this
I have checked the reorder function and everything that it does is to get the posts sorted and moveDown for each post

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use reorder I added a new `sort` column in the database which to store the order. So now I have the function

```
function _sortPosts($newSort){
foreach ($newSort AS $id => $value) {
if(is_numeric($value['sort'])){$this->Post->updateAll(array('Post.sort' => $value['sort']),array('Post.id' => $id));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Non-numeric value given.', true),'default', array('class' => 'error'));
$this->redirect($this->referer());
}

}
foreach(array_keys($this->data['Post']) as $parent){
$this->Post->reorder(array('id' => $parent, 'field' => 'Post.sort', 'order' => 'ASC', 'verify' => true));
}
}
```

But it is executed really slow if there are more than 20-30 children.
Here I have pasted an example of queries generated from changing order of one parent and 2 children: http://pastebin.com/e076Czg5